# Data Structure - For multiple possible keys types, if key is true, return subset of values

Tags: c#, data-structures

A quick example:

```
Tom, Mary and John say "I want an apple"
Tom and John say "I want a race car"
John and Mary say "I want a pretty dress."

DataStructure[Tom] returns --> "I want an apple";"I want a racecar";
DataStructure[Mary] returns --> "I want an apple";"I want a pretty dress";
```

What is the idea data structure?  If the number of keys or values can change?  Where I could presumably type DataStructure.Add(Mary, "New String); or DataStructure.AddWithNewKey("Timmy", List)?

---

Is there a better way than keeping a list or array of strings for each person?

---

In the comments below, I was confused as to why it would matter if the data was known at compile time or was purely dynamic.  Jon has pointed out that if the data was to be built dynamically, the ideal would be a dictionary related the string values to the people.  Otherwise his linq solution is quite nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want an [`ILookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx) - a map from keys to multiple values. You can create this using the [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) method in LINQ. Alternatively, if you want to build something similar up in a mutable fashion, you can use a `Dictionary<,>` where the type of the *value* is a list of some kind, e.g. `Dictionary<string, IList<string>>`. This is just a bit more fiddly than using a lookup, and doesn't behave as elegantly for missing keys.

The best solution will partly depend on how you're getting your data, mind you. It's not really clear from your example.

EDIT: You wouldn't want a `Lookup<bool, StringInfo>`. You'd want a `Lookup<Person, string>` where `Person` was an enum of `Tom`, `Mary`, `John` or something similar. The fact that these are hard-coded as properties is awkward, but not insurmountable. I would add a utility method like this:

```
static IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople(StringInfo input)
{
    // I don't normally use this formatting, but it's cleaner than the
    // alternatives in this particular case.
    if (input.Mary) yield return Person.Mary;
    if (input.Tom) yield return Person.Tom;
    if (input.John) yield return Person.John;
}
```

You can then use:

```
var lookup = allStringInfos
       .SelectMany(info => GetPeople(info),
                   (info, person) => new { text = info.stringInfo, person })
       .ToLookup(pair => pair.person,
                 pair => pair.text);
```

Then:

```
foreach (string value in lookup[Person.John])
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @RobertChrist: So you really have hard-coded keys like that, with just true/false values? Hmm. You certainly *could* still use a lookup, but it's not an ideal format for a LINQ query.

Comment: @RobertChrist: Being hard-coded in separate properties makes them awkward to fetch from a LINQ query. If you each input value had a sequence of keys associated with it, that would be much easier to query.

Comment: @RobertChrist: Look at my edited answer. Once you've used `ToLookup`, you shouldn't need to do anything else.

Comment: @RobertChrist: Well *something* needs to iterate over the input values. You won't find *any* way of using the data without iterating over it. So it might as well be simple...

Comment: @RobertChrist: How are you going to presort the array without ever iterating over it? `ToLookup` will iterate over the whole sequence *once*, and then it's done. After that, it doesn't need to touch the original data. If you're going to allow initialization work such as pre-sorting, why would you not allow that with a LINQ solution?

Comment: @RobertChrist: What add? You said you give a preset list of values. So you build a lookup from those values as shown, and you're done.

Comment: And what do I do if halfway through my program, I need to store a new, dynamically created string - key pair?

Comment: @RobertChrist: Then I'd possibly move to a `Dictionary<Person, IList<string>>` solution. But personally I'd *try* to always keep to an immutable lookup, potentially replacing one lookup with another periodically. It's much nicer to work with. At this point, I think we really need to stop with the comments - and I need to cook dinner...

Comment: Please clean up the comments that are no longer useful to the internet at large. If there are comments that are useful to the internet at large, they should be made clarifications (edits) on the question or answer as appropriate.